# Unable to get city name by current latitude and longitude in swift

Tags: ios, swift, clgeocoder, currentlocation

I'm trying to get city name from my current location coordiate by using `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation`.

It gives me country name, street name, state and many other things but not **city**. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placeMark, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Some errors: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }else{
            if let place = placeMark?[0]{
                print("country: \(place.administrativeArea)")

                self.lblCurrentLocation.text = place.administrativeArea
            }
        }
    } }
```

I use the below code too. But doesn't work for me. Here's the another way.

```
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]

        // Address dictionary
        print(placeMark.addressDictionary as Any)

        // Location name
        if let locationName = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Name"] as? NSString {
            print("locationName: \(locationName)")
        }
        // Street address
        if let street = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Thoroughfare"] as? NSString {
            print("street: \(street)")
        }
        // City
        if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["City"] as? NSString {
            print("city : \(city)")
        }
        // Zip code
        if let zip = placeMark.addressDictionary!["ZIP"] as? NSString {
            print("zip :\(zip)")
        }
        // Country
        if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? NSString {
            print("country :\(country)")
        }
    })
```

Please someone help me to get city name.

Comment: Doesn't the output of the line `print(placeMark.addressDictionary as Any)` give a hint?

Comment: Which latitude and longitude do you use ?

Comment: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)! 
I have used currend location latitude and longitude. Yes the drop down hint gives many options but non of them gives the city name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field is called **locality**

```
 if let locality = placeMark.addressDictionary!["locality"] as? NSString {
            print("locality :\(locality)")
        }
```

Locality Apple docs

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark/1423507-locality?language=objc

CLPlacemark

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark?language=objc

**Update:**

Try this

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
let location = CLLocation(latitude: 40.730610, longitude:  -73.935242) // <- New York

geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, _) -> Void in

    placemarks?.forEach { (placemark) in

        if let city = placemark.locality { print(city) } // Prints "New York"
    }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't execute the print line. Above code is printing street, country, locationName but not city. I've tried ["Locality"] and ["locality"] too.

Comment: It prints "New York" on above mentioned coordinate but doesn't work on Nepal's coordinate.

Comment: It means that this location is not complete on Apple's register. But the field is the one I told. In this case there is nothing to do.